# zooming map around center part of visible portion

Tags: javascript, math, createjs

I am working on a program which contains worldmap having countries, zoomin and zoomout button,left,right,top,bottom shift buttons. when we click zoom button then map gets zoomed regarding the center point. i am making this using createjs.

```
var lib.MCWorldMap = function() {
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Container();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-562.9,-337.9,1163.6,666.9);
})(lib = lib||{}, images = images||{});
```

when we added this worldmap on our stage then (0,0) is at the center (1163.6,666.9) is top left corner and (-1163.6,-666.9) is bottom right corner.
eg. i added this worldmap on canvas of size 600x400 as follows

```
var worldmap  = new lib.worldmap();
worldmap.setTransform(286.25,179,.473,.473);
```

i am zooming this by scaling x and y. lets says by 5%. after each zoom map is expanding  to all four sides with respect to center.
But when the center part changes by clicking shift buttons then also it is zooming regarding center part of the map. is there any to that we can zoom it regarding maps part present in the center of canvas not with respect to center part of the map as center part of the map always changes position on clicking shift buttons.